# Trying to read a webpage for stock information, and have it calculate my profit, but can't get float to work

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from lxml import HTML

r_disney= requests.get(
"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BUG?p=BUG&.tsrc=fin-srch")
html_disney = BeautifulSoup(r_disney.text, "lxml")
price_disney = html_disney.find(
"span", class_="fin-streamer Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")

price_disney = float(price_disney)

shares_disney = 20

purchased_disney = 177.27

capital_disney = float(purchased_disney * shares_disney)

disney_profit = float(price_disney * shares_disney) - (capital_disney)
```

The main issue I am having is I need to get the data from the webpage, then just have python do a few simple equations to calculate the profit, I would be making, but I can't make it do the equations. If you could please explain very simple that would be great, I am a python beginner so I don't know much.

Comment: Why not use Yahoo Finance's API instead of scraping the page?

Comment: Because I had no idea that existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is for scraping the data, then `price_disney = html_disney.find( "span", class_="fin-streamer Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")` is incorrect.

To get the tag `fin-streamer` and class `Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)` your code would be
`price_disney=html_disney.find("fin-streamer", {"class": "Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}).text` and then you can type cast it to float. So code will be like

`price_disney=html_disney.find("fin-streamer", {"class": "Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}).text`

yahoo api can be [explored](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help the only issue is now that this line won't work 
    disney_profit = float(price_disney * shares_disney) - (capital_disney)
It now responds saying the file type is unsupported for the *: 'Nonetype' and 'int'

Comment: may I know the error? pls post the screen snap of the error. i ran the complete code and did not find any error.

Comment: Yes here is a link: https://imgur.com/a/3NU4WSH

Comment: you have added 2nd variables, some is of none type, pls add the complete code,so can be advised further.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that but they run the same as previously shown and I can fix that by myself, the only issue I have currently is that the program seems to be running the numbers wrong. The number is should be giving should be around -400 but it gives near -3000

Comment: Never mind, I also figured out that issue it was a simple case of me not having to change the link used for the web scrapping. Regardless Thank you for your help

Comment: awesome! pls select response as answer and hope u liked stackoverflow :)